location of dance classes
The pie chart description says "location of dance classes", which confuses me. I don't know it's 48% of what? Does the pie chart represent dance classes or participants?

48% of dance classes are held in private studios.


48% of participants attend dance classes in private studios.



This isn't really a language question, but I would understand it to mean the proportions of classes held in the different types of location.

My (default?) assumption is that a dance class refers to one class held at one location, with multiple attendees. But if those classes are being counted by location, I'd expect that if one dance class is held on three different evenings every week, and another one only runs on one day a week, each of those would contribute one to the total being charted (regardless of whether those two different classes are held at the same location as each other). Others (including whoever composed the chart) might count things differently.

The labeling of the pie chart is undoubtedly ambiguous. If in the original it does show up immediately before the bar chart (whose horizontal axis is clear labeled), then I’d guess that the pie chart too is counting students rather than classss.

It's definitely ambiguous, and the fact that you are confused means you understand it quite well.

Come on now. Does the pie chart represent dance classes or participants? It states: location and types of dance classes. Participants are not mentioned. How can that be confusing? -1.

I’m voting to close this question because it's about poor data presentation, not language.

(I thought at first the question would be about the curious fact that the author uses "location" (singular) of classes, but "types" (plural).)

I've voted to close.  As you know, these are based on "made up" data, so it's not really possible to say what it really means. If it was "real" you'd probably need to look in detail at the source data, since people are notoriously bad at maths and frequently make mistakes on things like "percentage of what". You can't tell what is true from what is written, because people who write such things are frequently confused about percentages themselves.  Fortunately, since this is "made up" data, it doesn't matter.  ANd moreover for the test the examiner almost certainly won't understand percentages.

Since there's a further breakdown by age group, one can reasonably assume that a tuple of detail data in the dataset on which the chart is based contains the following pieces of data at a minimum:
location type
age of dance student
dance class type 

with no uniqueness constraint placed upon the tuple: the same location type could have multiple ballet classes, for example, and multiple students of the same age.
The percentages of the pie chart would be based on the number of students by location-type divided by total number of students.
P.S. If the numerator were the number of classes by location, and the denominator the total number of classes, the chart would be relatively meaningless, as it's possible that a location type with many poorly attended classes could appear as having the lion's share of classes, when population-wise it would be the worst.
P.P.S. The description also includes the phrase "dance classes young people in a town in Australia are attending" [my emphasis] and that is further evidence in  favor of understanding the pie-chart as being population-based.

You're so smart!

OP contains a pie chart and a bar chart, clearly marked what each represents.
I think the confusion arose because OP tried to compare apples to oranges.
The two charts show different data. OP had asked whether the data in pie chart means

48% of dance classes are held in private studios.
48% of participants attend dance classes in private studios.

How can it mean 48% of participants when the title mentions the location of dance classes?
Understanding the pie chart:.
Let us consider there are 100 classes of different dances.
The total number of classes (100) = 48 + 24 + 18 + 10
(The same studio may be teaching various forms of dances so the total number of studios would be less than 100. We are unable to find the actual number of studios with the given data).
Understanding the bar chart..
In this children are divided into two age groups. Below 11 and between 11 & 16.
By this chart we can understand, for example - how many students under 11 are learning Ballet, Tap or Modern. Again we are unable to find the actual total number of students as the same students may be learning different dance forms.
How these charts are useful:.
This type of data is called Market Research.. Suppose a client wants to start a new dance studio. He can decide where to locate (right location is everything), which age group to target and he can decide his marketing strategy.

The pie chart is titled Location of dance classes, not Number of dance classes.   Hence we can’t say it means the first sentence unless we can assume uniform usage of the studios across all locations.
To mean the second sentence, we need a further assumption of uniform class sizes.
